# Is "alike-looking" acceptable?

Tags: adjectives

Example:

> Characters `l` and `1` look alike.

Can I write the following?

> This table contains 6 alike-looking characters.

Comment: Much more idiomatic is **similar looking**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Alike-looking* isn't a common phrase, and sounds quite clumsy. Consider, on the other hand, **look-alike**, which means:

> a person or thing that closely resembles another, especially someone who looks very similar to a famous person.

Source: [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries/definition/look-alike)

This would make your phrase:

> This table contains 6 look-alike characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it, technically. It's slightly shorter than "6 characters that look alike," but it sounds awkward, like you have flipped around the sentence for no real reason. "6 similar looking characters" also works well.